# ColdFusion Dynamic JavaScript added for Datepicker class

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

**My Question:** Where/How do I edit the JavaScript that is dynamically added to the header of my CF page when the cfinput 'datefield' is present on the page?

**Example:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */
    ColdFusion.Ajax.importTag('CFINPUT-DATEFIELD');
/* ]]> */</script>

        <script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */
            var _cf_DATEFIELD_init_1431533171055=function()
            {
                ColdFusion.Calendar.setUpCalendar("sDate", "MM/DD/YYYY", 0, ["S","M","T","W","T","F","S"], ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"], 'balanceReportForm', null);
            };ColdFusion.Event.registerOnLoad(_cf_DATEFIELD_init_1431533171055);
        /* ]]> */</script>
```

The above JavaScript is added to my page when the following input is present in a form.

```
<cfinput type="datefield" name="sDate" value="" validate="date" validateat="onsubmit" message="Use the date selector to choose a start date." label="test" style="rollOverColor:##777777; selectionColor:##777777; todayColor:##777777">
```

Comment: You can't. That is why you should not be using the CF ui tags. You are stuck with the limited functionality that they give you. Use one of the myriad of popular JavaScript libraries instead.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I will explore other options.

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way

Comment: Just one example - [jQuery UI Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and another from [ColdFusion UI the Right Way](https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way/blob/master/chapters/cfinput/index.md)